# JS get element id array

Tags: javascript

My html code is

```
<select id="child[1]" name="child[1]">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="child[2]" name="child[2]">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

My JS code not working

JS code is

```
alert(jQuery("#child").length);
```

Can you  please help me how can I get the child array, I want to send the array through AJAX

Comment: alert(jQuery("#child[1]").length);

Answer (score 1):

change your jquery selector to

```
jQuery("[name*=child\\[]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("select[name^=child]").serializeArray()
```

what this does is:

1. get `select` elements that have a name *that starts with* "child"
2. serializes them into an array

the output is something like:

```
[
    {name:'child[1]', value:'1'},
    {name:'child[2]', value:'1'}
]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qdK7V/1/